# cant get onclick activeClass to work

Tags: jquery

I have four buttons with an onclick event that changes the content bellow. I am trying to add

a) an active class so that the hover effect sticks to the clicked button

b) when the page loads to have the first button already active

I have searched and tried a few approaches, but with my limited knowledge of js and jquery I'm quite lost. This is what I tried last

jquery:

```
// this script works
$("#partnering-nav a").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$(".toggle").hide();
var toShow = $(this).attr('href');
$(toShow).show();
});

// here I am lost
var selector = '#partner-box';

$(selector).on('click', function(){
$(selector).removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
});
```

I made a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tnLgu9hx/2/

Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. `partner-box` is a class, not an id, so your selector should be `.partner-box`
2. `active` is a class you are adding, not a pseudo-class, i.e. `:hover`.  `:active` is a browser controlled pseudo-class that tells when a link is being actively clicked.  You cannot modify this via JavaScript.  But, you can add a standard class.  If you add `.partner-box.active` to your CSS, it should work.

CSS:

```
.partner-box.active,
.partner-box:hover,
.partner-box:active,
.partner-box:target {
  background: #d96580;
  color: #fff;
  background-image: url(img/Partnering/arrow-hover.png);
  background-position: 105px 185px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Fixed selector:

```
var selector = '.partner-box';
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tnLgu9hx/3/

Comment: This solved it, thank you very much! Also thanks for the explanation, appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

i write the new code to make it easy to understand

a) the active class will transfer to the btn which you click

b) btn1 have active class by default

[codepen](https://codepen.io/kadai0308/pen/BWVaJg)

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="btn active">btn1</div>
    <div class="btn">btn2</div>
    <div class="btn">btn3</div>
    <div class="btn">btn4</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
}

.btn {
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

.btn:hover, .btn.active {
  background-color: #d96580;
}
```

JS(JQuery):

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active')
})
```

Comment: Thank you kindly, now I also have an active class when loading the page! :)